# Visual Studio Intellisense: How to add missing XML documentation

Tags: xml, intellisense

I am adding a driver reference (.dll) in MS Visual Studio 2010. But the problem is that the intellisense documentation is missing (also object browser) comments. When I go to the assembly location, there is the XML file with documentation. Why doesn't MS Visual Studio find the XML documentation?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the assembly you are referencing is actually the assembly you think you are referencing.

1. In **Solution Explorer**, expand the **References** node for your project and locate the reference. Right click the reference and select **Properties**.
2. In the **Properties** window, look at the **Path** property, and verify that the actual path to the assembly matches the path you were expecting. If it doesn't, look in the actual location for the .XML file containing the documentation comments.

Second, make sure the XML comments file actually contains comments for the items you are attempting to use. The author of the assembly may have omitted comments for some (or all) items defined in the assembly and still shipped the XML file.

1. Open the XML file and locate the element matching item(s) you have observed in the **Object Browser** to not have summary information.